# TYPO3 FAL: See sys_file uid in Backend

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, fal

(How) is it possible to see the sys_file uid of a document in the TYPO3 6.2 backend? When editing the metadata or hovering over the entry's icon, only the sys_file_metadata uid is displayed - which is of no use when making a link in the form of `<link file:3050>`.

A user asked me for this, as she'd like to use the file's uid for editing file links in tables, so she doesn't have to switch the cType from table to text to create the link.

Could it be a missing feature?

Comment: Which `cType` do you mean exactly?

Comment: Switching cType from `table` to `text` to get the RTE. After adding links, switch back to `table`.

Comment: TBH I didn't use Table cType since 8 years... always was using RTE within Text@Image CE, consider if it isn't easier approach. Remember, that currently with jQuery-everywhere you can replace CSS classes with easy for almost everything ;) Of course using RTE you have possibility just to use the LinkWizard for file selecting.

Comment: Other _semi solution_ is using the CE's Header Link field - which is used in every CE - she can just use the LinkWizard icon opposite to it, select the file and the it will be filled with `file:123` so she can copy it and paste in the table

Comment: Perfect workaround! For the future, I've opened a ticket on https://forge.typo3.org/issues/65470